# Return a multiple array in array in a Swift 3 function

Tags: arrays, swift, function, swift3

I have a doubt regarding return a value in array,

```
var data = [[Int](),[Int]()]
```

How to return the data in a function?

```
func test() ->[[Int](),[Int]()] // this giving me error {

}
```

How to return multiple array in single array in Swift?

Comment: fun test() -> [[Int]] { }

Comment: how about returning a touple? `func test() -> ([Int], [Int]){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `[[Int](),[Int]()]` is `[[Int]]` (same as `Array<Array<Int>>`), 
i.e. an array whose elements are arrays of `Int`:

```
func test() -> [[Int]] {
    let data = [[Int](),[Int]()]
    return data
}
```